# Initializing an HTML Template Image Attribute at Runtime

Tags: javascript, html, templates

The [htmlrocks rock article - html's new template tag](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/) initializes the image attribute of a template like this:

```
var t = document.querySelector('#mytemplate');
// Populate the src at runtime.
t.content.querySelector('img').src = 'logo.png';

var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
document.body.appendChild(clone);
```

Is this the correct way to initialize it?  It seems like we should be performing the operation that initializes the image attribute on the clone rather than the `t` variable.  I'm assuming that if we perform the operation on the `t` variable, then that actually rewrites the template, whereas if we do it on the `clone` then the template remains as is / unmodified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no practical difference unless you ever need the original value of the `src` attribute. Since the linked example has `src=""`, which makes no sense in HTML, that will never be the case for that example.